# Simple Calculation of Potentials for a hydrogen-oxygen Fuel cell, unexpected results from book example

Tags: electrochemistry, hydrogen, electricity, nernst-equation, chemical-potential

I am reading "Alternative energy systems" by Hodge.
On the fuel cell section, the author has an example for calculating the potential required for the fuel cell as a function of temperature and the pressure of the products and reactants (examples 10.1 and 10.2).
The author calculates equilibrium voltage with n=2, author establishes that:
$$\Delta G^\circ _\ce{H2O}=\pu{-229kJ/mol}$$

However, when he evaluates the equilibrium potential he takes $\Delta G^\circ _\ce{H2O}=\pu{229kJ/mol}$

Later on, the author calculates the deviation of equilibrium potential when oxygen is provided at 0.21 atm pressure using Nernst equation.
$$U = U^\circ -\frac{RT}{nF}\ln\left(\frac{P_\ce{H2O}}{\sqrt{P_\ce{O2}}P_\ce{H2}}\right)$$

Keeping the sign convention where $\Delta G < 0 \rightarrow \mathrm{energy~production}$, I get negative potentials, at standard conditions I get the same potential as the author (just different sign). Keeping the negative sign in my case shows that for air at 0.21 atm the potential becomes more negative, giving me a higher absolute potential. The author on the other hand, since they removed the negative sign, when they apply Nernst eqn, showing a lower absolute potential to drive the equation.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why is it being downvoted? Please let me know if anything is not clear or If I should provide more details into the author's work.

Comment: *Keeping the sign convention where ΔG<0→energy production, I get negative potentials.* - Why, when $\Delta_\text{r} G = -nF \cdot U$ ?

Comment: You're completely right, the author writes it without the negative sign, but I have been reading a couple more electrochem books and they all stated the same formula as you. I'm guessing it is a mistake on the authors end.

Comment: Δ must be negative. If it were positive, the reaction in the fuel cell will not be spontaneous.  Δ is positive in an electrolysis, not in a fuel cell-

Comment: Agreed, I just submitted an errata form to Wiley. Thank you guys for your help.